# Junction box in dishwasher bay

Tags: electrical, junction-box

According to the NEC, is it permitted to put an electrical junction box inside a dishwasher bay behind the actual dishwasher?

If it ever had to be reached, which I hope is never, the dishwasher would need to be removed.

The junction box would not be supplying power to the dishwasher but supplying other ends. *I.E. it is a separate circuit than that of the dishwasher circuit.*

Comment: Does it supply only the dishwasher?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with the dishwasher.

Comment: What is the goal here, why do you need to have a junction box in the space behind the dishwasher ? Perhaps there is an alternative.

Comment: Because the stub wiring coming out of the floor is too short to reach anywhere else.

Comment: Where does it need to go, where does it come from. I am trying to get you to **explain what the goal is**. Perhaps there is another way to route the wiring.

Comment: It's a space + legacy wiring issue. Imagine if the wiring was coming out of the floor right behind the DW and was too short to reach anywhere else and you can't replace the wiring coming out of the floor because it would require demolition of a separate unit

Comment: Assume the wiring coming in behind the DW is fixed and cannot be replaced

Comment: Imagine that, if I were to have the DW there, the only alternative to a JB in the bay was to hard wire behind the wall and hope no one ever finds out before the next demolition, which would be illegal

Comment: Is the wire long enough to place the JB in the sink cabinet? (assuming the DW is next to the sink).

Comment: I guess it comes down to how someone interprets the phrase "must be accessible" in the NEC as it regards junction boxes.  A JB covered with drywall is prohibited.  An outlet behind a refrigerator is allowed.  What about a JB behind the refrig?

Comment: It might but the thing is there are 4 cables and, to avoid overcrowdedness under the sink, I would like some JBs to be behind the DW. Having 3-4 JB around the plumbing is not my idea of clean and minimalist

Comment: If it is Romex there are in wall splices that are legal expensive but allowed by code.

Comment: Really? Please share what they are

Comment: Type in non metallic splice kit , OR  Romex splice kit big box stores have them specialty stores have them easy to use many don’t know about them.

Comment: @SteveSh -- a JB behind a fridge isn't an issue since you can stick a receptacle there

Comment: @stevesh look up accessible in the definitions of the code book. I make panels designed to be removed all the time I usually use some trim to hide the cut   As long as the finish is not messed up it is cool I use Velcro but an inspector told me screws are ok.

Comment: @Ed Beal - Thanks. I was aware of the outlet-behind-the-dishwaser being allowed (that's what the installer for mine), but wasn't sure if a junction box fell into that same category.

Comment: @SteveSh 2017 NEC 422.16(B)(2)(6) now specifies a receptacle for a dishwasher shall be located in the space adjacent to the dishwasher.

Comment: @amphibient in wall splices https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/49/4927386c-f90e-4fc6-b8ae-6d113682d82a.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Use a Non-Metallic (NM) splice kit; these are allowed in a wall without a box, as per NEC 334.40(b). These run about $15.00, maybe more.
 A box can be accessible behind a panel designed to be removable, but a dishwasher would not meet that requirement for accessibility.

Added : tyco non metallic splice , 2 wire non metallic splice, 3 wire non metallic splice will all bring up the models available 14-21$ from what I saw today. I have a few, just in case I cut a cable in a wall.  I have no association with any of the mfg’s it is a product that has saved me time and $.

Comment: Did our edits collide? :/

Comment: @threephaseeel ? Not sure on edits I added the names so they were not just in the comments.